# Adding Line or separator to y axis in WPF Tool kit Line chart

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

1. I have added multiple Y axes to a single chart. Is it possible to add vertical lines in the `LinearAxis` and a scroll bar in below X axis? Please check out the image below:

[image: screenshot]

2. How to handle the zoom and pan Functionality in the WPF Toolkit Chart?

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please ask them separately. The second one is way too broad, however.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the toolkit already handles zoom as I'm sure I didn't implement that but had it.  Not sure if that included panning too.